# Disable audio clipping protection Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, realtek-hd-audio

I'm currently on **Windows 10 1903** , on a HP Pavillion 15 Laptop.
After updating to 1903 I noticed that the audio has some form of clipping protection or compression..

Where when listening to bass sounds it goes quiet.

My first diagnosis was to disable all enhancements. At the time I was using the latest Realtek Audio driver for my laptop.

That didn't work, I resulted in uninstalling Realtek driver and installing almost 10 different versions of the driver, even the UAD Realtek drivers.. but still, the same issue was there.

I tried, the default **High Definition Audio driver by Microsoft**.
Even with **enhancements disabled** and **Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device** mode off. All old realtek, DTS, DOLBY and other APO servces were uninstalled and deleted.

Nothing worked.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated. I suspect it has something to do [with this.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/audio-signal-processing-modes)

Comment: Where do you see audio clipping? Which play program are you using?

Comment: When using any program. I usually use Chrome, VLC , windows media player, Spotify. When playing bassy songs, the audible volume reduces. I actually want the audio clipping to occur, and not the volume reduced since my headphones are capable of handling the sound. Technically, I can't see the clipping but I know some APOs have a feature called "clipping protection" which is the effect I am experiencing.

Comment: Are you using an advanced codec pack? My favorite is [K-Lite](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm), where you might be able to find some codec parameter for this.

Comment: No, I don't use any custom codec. Though, I highly doubt its a codec issue. My suspicion is somewhere along the audio pipeline, a hidden Audio Processor is applying its effects. Since at the application level, audio playback is fine. It just before it gets to the driver, the sound stream is hijacked for lack of a better word and the volume reduced.

Comment: VLC doesn't use installed codecs, but other players might use codecs with parameters.